# RDS Proxy IAM role unable to retrieve credentials from secret

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-rds-proxy

I am trying to implement a proxy to our Aurora RDS instance, but having difficulty getting the IAM access to work properly. We have a microservice in an ECS container that is attempting to access the database. The steps I've followed so far:

- Created a secret containing the DB credentials
- Created the proxy with the following config options:

  - Engine compatibility: MySQL
  - Require TLS - enabled
  - Idle timeout: 20 minutes
  - Secret - Selected DB credential secret
  - IAM Role - Chose to create new role
  - IAM Authentication - Required
- Modified the policy of the proxy IAM role as per the details on [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/set-up-shared-database-connection-amazon-rds-proxy/).
- Enabled enhanced logging

When issuing GET requests to the microservice, I see the following in the CloudWatch logs:

> Credentials couldn't be retrieved. The IAM role "arn:our-proxy-role"
> is not authorized to read the AWS Secrets Manager secret with the ARN
> "arn:our-db-credential-secret"

Another interesting wrinkle to all of this: I pulled up the [policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp), selecting the RDS proxy role and all of the actions under the Secrets Manager service, and all actions show up as being allowed.

I would sincerely appreciate any kind of guidance to indicate what I'm missing here.

`arn:our-proxy-role`

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds-db:connect"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:dbuser:*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
                "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
                "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:our-db-credential-secret"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "GetSecretValue",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:our-db-credential-secret"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DecryptSecretValue",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:key/our-db-cluster"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "kms:ViaService": "secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: All actions for which resources? Did you specify the `arn:our-db-credential-secret` resource? Can you please share your full IAM policies & permissions for `arn:our-proxy-role`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - Updated the post with the policy.

Comment: @GS-Scooter A couple questions:
(1) Did you use the plicy simulator with the specific target secret ARN?
(2) Does you secret have a resource policy that has a "Deny" in it?

Comment: @AslanBrooke - Yes, I used the specific role and secret ARN in the simulator. The secret does not have any additional policy specified, so there's no explicit Deny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to security groups. I needed to specify an additional inbound rule to allow incoming traffic from itself so as to facilitate communication between resources that are part of the same security group.